# emulator: ERROR: There is no user data image in your build directory. Please make a full build

Tags: android-emulator, android-source, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm doing android open source project and I'm new to aosp.
I am building gingerbread in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

I have managed to successfully compile the source code without any error, and now when I run the command 'emulator', I get the following error and my emulator is not running at all

```
emulator: WARNING: ignoring locked user data image at /home/hari/Android/aosp/out/target/product/generic/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: WARNING: Another emulator is running. user data changes will *NOT* be saved
emulator: ERROR: There is no user data image in your build directory. Please make a full build
```

I searched over the internet and was not able to find a guy with the similar problem. So, anyone have any idea? What could be the possible solution ?

**Edit:**
My out directory and userdata-qemu.img is locked! Is this unusual ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When pasting source code or logs, please indent them by 4 spaces so it get the correct formatting without using the ` symbol

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JohnKiller. And I'm sorry coz, this is my first query in StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your file is locked... may be you copied some files from another user. Make sure you give the all your files some permissions.

cd one step back from your aosp root directory and use this command

```
chmod -Rv 755 youraospdirectory/
```

I had similar issues, but in my case the whole directory was the problem.
So it would be better to chmod the whole directory.

Comment: Yup! that's the trick. But for me, the out directory and the userdata-qemu.img was causing the problem. I used chmod command there alone to solve my case.