# AOSP Android 12 Beta version build fails

Tags: android-source, android-12

I've tried to compile AOSP android 12 beta branches with no success.

I cloned the repo using:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b refs/tags/android-s-beta-3
repo sync
```

and then used:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_blueline-userdebug
m
```

now when it starts to run, after a while, it fails because there's duplication at the stub libraries:

```
[ 95% 86/90] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --out "out/soong"     -n "out"     -d "out/soong/build.ninja.d"     -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used Android.bp
error: build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp:130:1: module "legacy.core.platform.api.stubs" already defined
       libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api/Android.bp:182:1 <-- previous definition here
error: build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp:146:1: module "stable.core.platform.api.stubs" already defined
       libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api/Android.bp:198:1 <-- previous definition here
error: build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp:164:1: module "legacy-core-platform-api-stubs-system-modules" already defined
       libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api/Android.bp:216:1 <-- previous definition here
error: build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp:180:1: module "stable-core-platform-api-stubs-system-modules" already defined
       libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api/Android.bp:232:1 <-- previous definition here
error: libcore/JavaLibrary.bp:994:1: module "core.current.stubs" already defined
       build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp:27:1 <-- previous definition here
error: libcore/JavaLibrary.bp:1015:1: module "core-current-stubs-for-system-modules" already defined
       build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp:48:1 <-- previous definition here
error: libcore/JavaLibrary.bp:1041:1: module "core-current-stubs-system-modules" already defined
       build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp:74:1 <-- previous definition here
```

I've also tried to change the build/soong branch to master and I've got another build faliure.

How do I compile those beta versions? what am I missing??

Moreover, all the Android 12 betas I've tried are broken.  [For example, another beta 1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673531/android-12-beta-1-aosp-build-fail)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so finally I've got this beta version compiled.
The thing I've found is that beta branch/ tag is not necessarily compiling.

So what I did is looking at:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/

and when I ran into errors I've tried to checkout a later commit for this problematic sub-module that fixes this compilation.
Doing this until finding a combination of commits that compiled together did the magic.

If someone would like to know which specific commit I've checkout in order to get Android 12 beta 2 compiled just tell me

Comment: Hi OmB, I managed to compile the beta2 in my pc, but when I try to open the emulator, error occur: 
qemu-system-x86_64: Could not open '/home/AOSP_12_beta2/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img': No such file or directory, 
do you meet this before? Thanks

Comment: Also, if you doen't encounter this issue, could you please share the commit you have checkout, appreciated.

Comment: Hi JerryLin,
I'm build it for a physical device so the userdata image is generated for me but have you tried to search for userdata image not gererated topics like this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926469/emulator-error-there-is-no-user-data-image-in-your-build-directory-please-mak

Also the branches I've check out is:
external/libchrome/                     branch master,
external/rust/crates/shared_child/      branch master,
packages/modules/NeuralNetworks a1191b55fc209e2f685c8eb788e8237280660299

Comment: Thanks for replying OmB! I tried to add the permission, but that didn't work... could u please tell where you download the related driver/vendor files for physical device? Maybe I can try build to physical device too.    here is the [link](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading#downloading-proprietary-binaries) for where I download the proprietary binaries. Both preview version and newest release version not work.

Comment: Hi Jerry! This is the correct place, from where I've downloaded the drivers.
Are you using Pixel devices? if so, which Pixel (4,4 XL,5) ? you need to take the preview binaries from here https://developers.google.com/android/blobs-preview.

Comment: I downloaded the pixel 4XL driver from the web, and unfortunately, I goe series error from this vendor, it says that 
vendor/qcom/coral/proprietary/libimsmedia_jni/android_arm64_armv8-a_shared/libimsmedia_jni.so: error: Unresolved symbol: _ZN7android10IInterface8asBinderERKNS_2spIS0_EE@LIBBINDER.

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: For errors I encountered above, it suggests me do this: add properties in Android.bp: allow_undefined_symbols: true, it succeeded in compilation, but when I flash into device, it will automatically enter fastboot mode with an error info "no valid slot to boot"

Comment: out/soong/.intermediates/vendor/qcom/coral/proprietary/libimsmedia_jni/android_arm64_armv8-a_shared/libimsmedia_jni.so: error: Unresolved symbol: _ZN7android10IInterface8asBinderERKNS_2spIS0_EE@LIBBINDER
out/soong/.intermediates/vendor/qcom/coral/proprietary/libimsmedia_jni/android_arm64_armv8-a_shared/libimsmedia_jni.so: note:
out/soong/.intermediates/vendor/qcom/coral/proprietary/libimsmedia_jni/android_arm64_armv8-a_shared/libimsmedia_jni.so: note: Some dependencies might be changed, thus the symbol(s) above cannot be resolved.

Comment: Hi Jerry,
Beta 4 is out today, maybe the vendor folder you've downloaded is for the new beta 4 version and that why it didn't compile.
I will download it today, check it and let you know

Comment: Thanks for your help! Looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem is that this AOSP 12 Beta 3 is not fully synced and few of the  modules were mentioned on different-2 files due to that you are getting these errors. I was also getting the same errors.
[image]

To get rid of these errors by commenting these modules in these files.

error: build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp:130:1: module "**legacy.core.platform.api.stubs**" already defined

libcore/mmodules/core_platform_api/Android.bp:182:1 <-- previous definition here

build/soong/java/core-libraries/Android.bp line 130 you can comment this module.
/*java_library {
name: "**legacy.core.platform.api.stubs**",
visibility: core_platform_visibility,
hostdex: true,
compile_dex: true,

```
sdk_version: "none",
system_modules: "none",
static_libs: [
    "art.module.public.api.stubs.module_lib",
    "conscrypt.module.platform.api.stubs",
    "legacy.i18n.module.platform.api.stubs",
],
patch_module: "java.base",
```

}*/
Same you have to do with other modules too.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4618429/omribager Have you build AOSP 12 Beta 3 successfully if yes, please mention the process because after these fixes also I am getting other modules issue.

[100% 1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --out "out/soong"     -n "out"     -d "out/soong/build.ninja.d"     -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used Android.bp
**error: external/rust/crates/zip/Android.bp:21:1: "libzip" depends on undefined module "libflate2"**
01:00:29 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

##### failed to build some targets (01:08 (mm:ss))

Comment: Hi Varun,
Thanks for replying me.
I tried this way of removing the duplicated stub libs, but I got more errors after that.
Moreover, there are commits that fixes those problems, so I've tried to check out those commits on the libcore submodule and it fixes it also but it seems there are a lot of other problem so I moved backwards and tried to compile beta 2.
I successfully compile and ran beta 2 so if you'd like help with this version I can tell you what commits to checkout

Comment: Hi @OmB, I have tried Android 12 Beta 2 but getting following error. Can you help me here.    [100% 1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --out "out/soong"     -n "out"   -d "out/soong/build.ninja.d"     -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o /soong/build.ninja --available_env 
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

Comment: Just share the branch name which I can use to build android 12 beta 2 . I am using following to get the code and build  **repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-s-beta-2**